# Oracle Linux 6.7 - Nohup: Argument list too long

Tags: rm, xargs, nohup, oracle-linux, oracle

There are 1 million directories and some files in directories (.pdf, .csv etc.) under the path I have specified below:

```
/data/upl/repo/exp/
```

I want all files and folders older than 1 year to be deleted, but I get the error I mentioned in the title.

Is the command I specified below correct to do this?

```
nohup find /data/upl/repo/exp/ -type d -mtime +365 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf &
```

Other than that, I couldn't find a good solution.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

> find /data/upl/repo/exp/ -type d -mtime +365 -exec rm -rf {} \;

???

Of course, that `rm -rf` is just asking for trouble.

I would delete the files first, then do an rmdir on the directories.